# Replace value with consecutive column across multiple columns r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
     Q1  Q1a    Q2    Q2a   Q2b
1   foo <NA>    fee   <NA>  <NA>
2   bar <NA>  other    ree  <NA>
3 other  roo    bee   <NA>  <NA>
4   bar <NA>    fee   <NA>  <NA>
5   bar <NA>  other    fee  <NA>
6 other  fee  other    <NA>  roo
```

I would like to replace any occurrence of 'other' with the value from the consecutive column in the same row (i.e. *Qx* a) so that I can get rid of the sparse columns:

```
     Q1    Q2  
1   foo   fee  
2   bar   ree
3   roo   bee 
4   bar   fee 
5   bar   fee
6   fee   roo
```

I could imagine doing this for one column like so:

```
Lines = "
Q1  Q1a    Q2    Q2a   Q2b
foo NA fee  NA  NA
bar NA other  ree  NA
other roo  bee   NA  NA
bar NA    fee   NA  NA
bar NA    other fee  NA
other  fee  other NA  roo"

df = read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)

df$Q1[df$Q1=='other'] = df$Q1a[df$Q1=='other']
```

and then looping through for each column, but this is a bit tiresome and slow with lots of columns and multiple values in each column.

Is there a neater way of doing this? (Also, my method wouldn't extend neatly to the Q2a Q2b example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `split` the dataset based on similar columns, then loop through the `list` of `data.frame`s and replace the values that are 'other' based on the index created with `max.col`

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(df, sub("[a-z]+$", "", names(df))), function(x) {
          i1 <- x[,1] == "other"
          i2 <- x[-1] != "other" & !is.na(x[-1])
          x[,1][i1] <- x[-1][cbind(1:nrow(i2), (max.col(i2))* i1)]
       x[,1]
  }))
#   Q1  Q2
#1 foo fee
#2 bar ree
#3 roo bee
#4 bar fee
#5 bar fee
#6 fee roo
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
split.default(df, sub("[a-z]+$", "", names(df))) %>%
       map_df(~ replace(., .== 'other', NA) %>% 
                 do.call(paste, .) %>%
                 gsub("\\s*|(NA\\s*)+", "", .))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#     Q1    Q2
#   <chr> <chr>
#1   foo   fee
#2   bar   ree
#3   roo   bee
#4   bar   fee
#5   bar   fee
#6   fee   roo
```

Comment: I think you included `\\s*|` in the final gsub on your tidyverse solution because of my (potentially poorly formatted) example dataframe above. My real data contains strings with spaces, so removing this from the regex means your solution is perfect.

Comment: @TMrtSmith  Otherwise, you can remove that and use `trimws` i.e. `trimws(gsub("(NA\\s*)+", "", .)))`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't scale to like Q3a - Q3f but a quick-and-dirty solution would be..

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(Q1 = ifelse(Q1 == 'other', Q1a, Q1),
           Q2 = ifelse(Q2 == 'other', 
                       ifelse(!is.na(Q2a), Q2a, Q2b))) %>%
    select(Q1, Q2)
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have a Q3a-Q3f example

Comment: ah yeah, akrun's example then.